# element sometimes lost its scope binding

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

- Problem:

In jquery ajax response function, use angular.element(selector).scope() sometimes can not fetch its real scope. At least for chrome browser.

- How to repeat:

Put the following page in a web server. use chrome to visit it, press F12 to open dev console, click login/logout repeatedly. The printed id value should be "2", but sometimes it is "1". In my environment, "1" shows up in less than 10 times.

My environment: 
 chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), Linux foxsen-pc 4.2.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.2.6-3 (2015-12-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux. tomcat 8.5.13

- Analysis

I have tried to find out the root cause and find these facts:

1. if I load angular before jquery, it seems ok
2. if I comment out $("#sidebarControl").show, it seems ok
3. when I set breakpoints on the scripts, id == 1 never met
4. id == 1 not seen in Firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit) in the same machine
5. use console.log to print out $scope fetched, I find out that jqueryxxxx object is not in the body dom object in the case of scope.$id == "1". But I've tried to add code in the controller to do the same print in controller function, the jqueryxxx exists and scope.$id is "2". So it seems the binding jquery object(and the scope object stored in it) might be lost in some cases.

I know it is bad to mix the use of jquery and angular. I can fix the issue by using $http instead of $.ajax or just use $scope instead of fetching it from DOM. But I want to know why it will fail and what I am missing.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body ng-controller="sidebarControl" id="sidebarControl">
<div id="loginView">
     <form>
        <input type="button" style="width: 100%" value="login" ng-click="login()"/>
     </form>
</div>
<div id="indexView" style="display:none">
    <h2> This is a test! </h2>
    <input type="button" syle="width: 100%" ng-click="loginOut()" value="logout"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('sidebarControl', function ($scope) {

        $("#sidebarControl").show(); //without this line it seems ok

        var userData = getCookie("userData");
        if(typeof(userData) != 'undefined' && userData == "logged"){
                $("#loginView").hide();
                $("#indexView").show();
                console.log(userData);
        }

        $scope.login = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/huiyi", //any existing page
                success: function (m) {
                    setCookie("userData","logged");
                    $("#loginView").hide();
                    $("#indexView").show();

                    var ele = angular.element("#sidebarControl");
                    console.log(ele.scope().$id)
                    if (ele.scope().$id == "1"){
                        alert("scope is wrong!");
                        console.log(ele.scope())
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            })
        }

        $scope.loginOut = function () {
            delCookie("userData");
            window.location.href="test.html";
       }

       function getCookie(c_name) {
           if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
               c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
               if (c_start != -1) {
                   c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1
                   c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start)
                   if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length
                   return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end))
               }
           }
           return ""
       }
       function setCookie(name,value)
       {
           var Days = 180;
           var exp = new Date();
           exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + Days*24*60*60*1000);
           document.cookie = name + "="+ escape (value) + ";expires=" + exp.toGMTString();
       }
       function delCookie(name)
       {
           var exp = new Date();
           exp.setTime(exp.getTime() - 1);
           var cval=getCookie(name);
           if(cval!=null) document.cookie= name + "="+cval+";expires="+exp.toGMTString();
       }
    }) 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$scope` of your controller should be accessible, why using `ele.scope()`?

Comment: You are right. I realize that after finding the bug. As I stated, I just want to know why ele.scope() will fail to avoid misusage in other cases.

Comment: why you can be sure that it is incorrect when `$id==1`? `$id` is assigned and used by angular internally, user code should not rely on it.

Comment: it is only used to demo the abnormal, I have use console.log to log the whole scope object and find out that id == 1 means the actual scope's parent. At this time you can try to print out scope.login or other existing object assigned to the scope, it will be undefined.

Comment: $id == 1 should be rootScope. In this simple case the target scope $id should not be 1. Anyway you can change the other way to judge, such as:              if (!ele.scope().login){
                        alert("scope is wrong!");
                        console.log(ele.scope())
                    }